# Can't deploy EJB jar to TomEE in Eclipse ("no resources can be added to server")

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ejb, apache-tomee

I have a very simple Maven project with just one class and the pom. The class is annotated with `@Startup` and `@Singleton` and contains two methods, one annotated with `@PostConstruct` and the other with `@Schedule`.

The pom is simple as you can see below and I believe everything is in order as I can compile and deploy the project from the command line. However, I'd like to deploy it from Eclipse.

When I right-click on the TomEE server in Eclipse I get the following message: *There are no resources that can be added or removed from the server*.

I have enabled "EJB Module 3.1" and "Java 8" in the project's facets. If I activate "Dynamic Web Module" instead of "EJB Module" I can add the project to the server but it doesn't look like the EJB is deployed (breakpoint in `@PostConstruct` not hit and logs not printed).

What's wrong with Eclipse? Thanks a lot.

```java
@Startup
@Singleton
public class Jobs {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Jobs.class.getSimpleName());

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        log.info("EJB 'Jobs' created!");
    }

    @Schedule(second = "*/5", minute = "*", hour = "*")
    private void run() throws Exception {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>edu.self</groupId>
    <artifactId>name</artifactId>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>name</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Markers view in eclipse? you can open Markers view this way Window >> Views >> Markers

Comment: Nope, there's nothing...